Linux cgroup (v2): Why has setting memory.max no effect here?
I am trying to demonstrate the effect of limiting the memory consumption of a process in a Linux cgroup (v2) by setting memory.max, but executing the following commands as root seems to have no effect:
cd /sys/fs/cgroup 
echo +memory > cgroup.subtree_control      # enable memory controller
mkdir MemCG; echo 100M > MemCG/memory.max  # create cgroup with limited memory consumption
echo $$ > MemCG/cgroup.procs               # move current shell to this cgroup
alloc-mem 100 500                          # start child process that allocates memory

I expected alloc-mem to be killed when attempting to allocate 200 MB - however it runs to completion (up to 500 MB) without problems:
Allocating up 500 MB of memory in steps of 100 MB ...
Allocated and wrote 100 MB of memory.
Allocated and wrote 200 MB of memory.
Allocated and wrote 300 MB of memory.
Allocated and wrote 400 MB of memory.
Allocated and wrote 500 MB of memory. 

So, why is the memory.max limit not enforced here? When I run the same program not in a cgroup but in a Docker container started with --memory=100M, the program is terminated as it should be (hence, the problem is not with the program but with my usage of cgroup above).
I am using OpenSuSE Leap 15.5, running kernel 5.14.21.
Here is the memory allocation program, if that matters in any way:
/*
 * alloc-mem.c
 *
 * This programm allocates memory of the indicated size. It accepts either 
 * - a single long integer argument and allocates as many MB of heap space
 * or
 * - two long integer arguments, interpeted as a chunk size and a size limit
 *   (both in MB) and allocates heap space in chunks of the indicated size 
 *   until the sum of the chunk's sizes reaches or exceeds the limit.
 *
 * It is intended to test memory allocation limits.
 */

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

void* allocateMB(long nMB) {
    void* mem = calloc(1024 * 1024, nMB);
    if (mem == NULL) {
      long error = errno;
      perror("");
      exit(error);
      return NULL;  // never reached
    } else {
      memset(mem, -1, 1024 * 1024, nMB);
      printf("Allocated and wrote  %ld MB of memory.\n", nMB);
      return mem;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  long chunkSize = 0;
  long sizeLimit = 0;

  if (argc != 2 && argc != 3) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: EITHER %s <size of single memory chunk> OR %s <chunk size> <size limit> (all numbers in MB)\n", argv[0], argv[0]);
    return -1;
  }
  chunkSize = atol(argv[1]);
  if (argc == 3) {
    sizeLimit = atol(argv[2]);
  } else {
    sizeLimit = chunkSize;
  }
  
  printf("Allocating up %ld MB of memory in steps of %ld MB ...\n", sizeLimit, chunkSize);
  for (long nextSize = chunkSize; nextSize <= sizeLimit; nextSize += chunkSize) {
    void* mem = allocateMB(nextSize);
    free(mem);
  }                                       
  sleep(1); /* sleep 1 sec */

  return 0;
}


It may not allocate it until you try to write to it (if, for example, your use of the memory was sparse).  Try changing malloc(nMB * 1024 * 1024) to calloc(1024 * 1024, nMB) or add a memset(mem, 0, mMB * 1024 * 1024) after your call to malloc().

While that appeared plausible to me, too, replacing malloc by called did not change anyhthing, so the question is still open.

If you memset it all to something other than all zeros, does that change anything?

No, setting all bytes to -1 does not change anything. I still suspect that the problem is not with my test program, but with my handling of the cgroup, though.
